# Integrating Forefront Identity Manager with my Web Application

Tags: asp.net, web-services, federated-identity

I have googled for this for a while without success.  I need to build a web application/modify existing ones to use FIM (Forefront Identity Manager) for authentication.  This is the requirement for my company going forward as they are planing to implement FIM and so every application has to conform.  No resource or article shows API or web services to call to integrate FIM to a web application.  Everything I am seeing is how web services enable you to extend FIM.  Any Help in this will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FIM doesn't do authentication.  Instead, it does the user management and synchronization piece.

You would want to integrate with one of the directories FIM is synchronizing.  If your app is within the firewall, you would typically use AD or LDAP (Kerberos-based).  If your app is outside of the firewall, you would typically use Azure Active Directory or another SAML-based Identity Provider.